# Uploaded app build is not showing iTunesconnect

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

Two days before, I upload the ipa file through application loader.But build file not showing in the iTunes connect -> MyAppName -> Activity tab.

I'm planning to use testflight external beta testing. So following things done.

1. Separately created AppId
2. Separately created Profile(adhoc)

Note: 
Now I try to upload same file, I got error itms-4238 "Redundent binary upload. There already exists a binary upload with build version & train".
But in the iTunes connect -> MyAppName -> Activity nothing has been displayed.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem- build uploaded but not showing in activity tab.
This error on re-uploading means, binary file is already uploaded - no problem with upload.

this happens when your binary (.ipa) has some issue. itunesconnect remove it from activity and send mail to relavant mail - id with detail of error.

Please check you email - email which you have used for registering with itunesconnect. There must be an email with error description.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue as you have. Mine one is display on Activity tab for sometimes. As soon as I refreshed page, it will hide.

I figure out my issue. My issue is in **info.plist** file. **The description of attached image key is missing.**

[image]

I entered proper description and it will work for me.

Comment: I have missing this key  "Privacy - Camera Usage Description" description.Thank you.